# Table inside of another table?

Tags: lua

I found source code of Lua with something like this:

```
mytable={}
table.insert(mytable, {a, b, c, d, e, f})
...
```

If I understand the source code, it is something what I need in my program, but I would like to read something more about this data structure, how it works etc. Could someone help me, what exactly is it? I found a lot of articles about tables in Lua, but I didn't find this form which I mentioned. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua-table/info

Comment: A Lua table can contain itself!

Comment: Equivalent to `mytable = { { a, b, c, d, e, f } }` and `mytable = { [1] = { [1]=a, [2]=b, [3]=c, [4]=d, [5]=e, [6]=f } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lua table can contain almost any value: strings, integers, functions and, yes, even tables - only `nil` is not allowed. [From the docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) (emphasis mine):

> [...] they can contain values of all types (except **nil**).

So here `table.insert` will simply add the table passed as the second argument to the next available position in `mytable`.

[`table.insert` reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.insert)

[Wikipedia on associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)